# Why does this code encodes random salt first as hexadecimal digits?

Tags: authentication, cryptography, salt

I'm looking at some existing code that is generating a salt which is used as input into an authentication hash.

The salt is 16 bytes long, and is generated by first using an OS random number generator to get 8 bytes of random data.

Then each byte in the 8 byte buffer is used to place data into 2 bytes of the 16 byte buffer as follows:

```
out[j]   = hexTable[data[i] & 0xF];
out[j-1] = hexTable[data[i] >> 4 & 0xF];
```

Where `out` is the 16 byte salt, `data` is the initial 8 byte buffer, `j` and `i` are just loop incrementers obviously, and `hexTable` is just an array of the hex digits i.e. `0` to `F`.

Why is all this being done? Why isn't the 16 byte salt just populated with random data to begin with? Why go through this elaborate process?

Is what is being done here a standard way of generating salts? What's the benefit and point of this over just generating 16 random bytes in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply conversion of your 8 random bytes to 16 hexadecimal digits.

It seems that someone misunderstood the concept of salt, or what input your hash needs, and thought it only accepts hexadecimal digits.

Maybe also the salt is stored somewhere where it is easier to store hexadecimal digits instead of pure bytes, and the programmer thought it would be good to be able to reuse the stored salt as-is (i.e. without converting it back to bytes first).